# why is if(!$_SESSION['dbname']){} returning false?

Tags: php, session

im not able to create a session.

my php code is

```
<?php 

          $dbhost = "localhost";
          $dbuser = "root";
          $dbpassword = "";
          $dbname = "dany";
          $query = "";
          $sqlQuery = ""; 
          $row = "";
          $username=false;
          if(isset($_POST['n'])){
              $username=$_POST['n'];
           }
          $password= false;
          if(isset($_POST['p'])){
              $password= $_POST['p'];
          }
          $conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname);
          $sUser=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
          $sPass=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);
          // For Security 
          $query="SELECT * From admin where username='$sUser' and password='$sPass'";
          $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
          if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
          {
              session_start();
              $_SESSION['dany']= $dbname;
              header('location:adminPanel.php');
          }
?>
```

the other code where the session is checked, the code is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['dany'])
{
    header('location:adminLogin.php');
}
?>
```

here the line:

```
if(!$_SESSION['dany'])
```

is returning false for every valid input i give as well as for the invalid inputs.
i tried to copy the whole code and create a new dummy project, it worked there. but is not working in my actula project.

Comment: `!$_SESSION...` is returning `false`…? Does that mean that it *goes into the `if`* or that it *doesn't go into the `if`*? Have you checked whether the session is *started* successfully in the first place (`mysqli_num_rows($result)==1` is `true`)?

Comment: @deceze if(!$_SESSION['dany']) returns true. which means $_SESSION['dany'] is equal to false. 
it goes into the if block. but i shouldn't, on valid inputs.

Comment: @deceze 
--- Undefined index: dany in "adminPanel.php" on line 3 ---
this is what im getting as an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the `dany` entry defined with `isset`:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['dany'])){
```

Comment: yea it did start working but now its working for all inputs, whether valid or invalid.i tried doing this
    if(isset($_SESSION['dany']))
    {
      header('location:form.php'); 
    }
    else if (is_null($_SESSION['dany'])){
      header('location:adminLogin.php');
    }
but this has the same effect

Comment: You don't need `else if (is_null($_SESSION['dany'])){ `, you can instead just use a simple `else {`.

Comment: i had tried that before. but it also didnt resolve the problem. i am still unable to create a session

Comment: Whenever you are testing sessions you need to terminate your session with `session_destroy()` to be able to test again. Otherwise the browser can keep your session state and make as if you were always logged

Comment: i have written that piece of code to terminate the session. but i will work if the session in created. i am unable to create the session. @Isac

Comment: What exact error are you getting and where? Also try `var_dump` on the `$result` after making the query to see if you are getting the expected results. On top of that make sure you don't have any enters or spaces before the starting `<?php` otherwise `session_start()` will fail